# How to connect to a WCF Service with IronPython

Tags: wcf, ironpython

Has anyone done this?  I've tried generating a c# proxy class and connecting through it, but I cannot figure out how to get IronPython to use the generated app.config file that defines the endpoint.  It tries to connect, but I just get an error about no default endpoint.  I would ideally like to make the connection using only IronPython code and not use the proxy class, if possible.  The binding for the service I am trying to connect to is a NetTcpBinding if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

See my [blog post](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2009/10/wcf-service-in-ironpython.html). There are IronPython WCF service and client examples.

To use app.config, you probably must copy it to `ipy.exe` and rename it to `ipy.exe.config` but I have not tried it so I don't know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is your WCF service interface available in a shared assembly?  If so, you could look at using the ChannelFactory to create your client proxy dynamically (instead of using the generated C# proxy).  With that method you can supply all the details of the endpoint when you create the ChannelFactory and you won't require any configuration in your .config file.

Comment: Any idea how to do that in IronPython?  I've tried that approach and it doesn't seem to work.  I got an error about some IronPython class not supporting reflection.

Comment: Sorry, that I don't know. I've never used IronPython.  That might be a good question for the CodePlex discussion forums for IronPython.